# Mule Log4j2 not working

Tags: log4j, mule

I have a log4j2 XML file in my src/main/resources as below. But Still I do not see the log file created. Any idea what could I be missing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <File name="file" fileName="C:\\Users\\Guest\\Desktop\\Mule.log">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m %ex%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </File>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="file" level="DEBUG"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" level="INFO"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log4j2 configuration works only in Mule-3.6 version+, check your Mule version and give file name to C:/Users/Guest/Desktop/Mule.log format.

Sample file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">${env:MULE_HOME}/logs/test</Property>
        <Property name="log-name">test</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console-log" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="info-log" fileName="${log-path}/${log-name}-info.log"
            filePattern="${log-path}/${log-name}-info-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
                </pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="debug-log" fileName="${log-path}/${log-name}-debug.log"
            filePattern="${log-path}/${log-name}-debug-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
                </pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="trace-log" fileName="${log-path}/${log-name}-trace.log"
            filePattern="${log-path}/${log-name}-trace-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
                </pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="error-log" fileName="${log-path}/${log-name}-error.log"
            filePattern="${log-path}/${log-name}-error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
                </pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <!-- CXF is used heavily by Mule for web services -->
        <AsyncLogger name="org.apache.cxf" level="WARN"/>

        <!-- Apache Commons tend to make a lot of noise which can clutter the log-->
        <AsyncLogger name="org.apache" level="WARN"/>

        <!-- Reduce startup noise -->
        <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.beans.factory" level="WARN"/>

        <!-- Mule classes -->
        <AsyncLogger name="org.mule" level="INFO"/>
        <AsyncLogger name="com.mulesoft" level="INFO"/>

        <!-- Reduce DM verbosity -->
        <AsyncLogger name="org.jetel" level="WARN"/>
        <AsyncLogger name="Tracking" level="WARN"/>

        <AsyncRoot level="DEBUG">
            <appender-ref ref="info-log" level="info" />
            <appender-ref ref="trace-log" level="trace" />
            <appender-ref ref="debug-log" level="debug" />
            <appender-ref ref="error-log" level="error" />
            <appender-ref ref="console-log" level="debug" />
        </AsyncRoot>

    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

For studio, specify location of MULE_HOME in Run Configuration->Environment->new->Name->MULE_HOME and Value->c:/test

Answer (score 0):

Try changing fileName to fileName="C:/Users/Guest/Desktop/Mule.log"